# Multiple Linear Regression - Any Red Flags

Tags: r, multiple-regression

I carried out a survey asking three questions based on a set of images presented to a user population. This was a web survey and users were allowed to select more than one answer.

Example questions:

```
Q1: How do you feel when you see this image? Select All that Applies
I feel Happy?
I feel Happy and energized? 
I feel sad? 
I feel enthusiastic.
```

In addition to answering these questions users were also asked to rate the quality of the image from 1-10 scale.

I have introduced dummy variable for each question and answers and prepared the following data set:

```
image_id, user_id, image_quality_rating, 1_1, 1_2, 1_3, 1_4, 2_1, 2_2...3_5
001, 131, 8.5, 1 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ..., 0
002, 131, 6.5, 0 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ..., 0
001, 231, 5.5, 0 , 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, ..., 0
...
```

Here: `1_1` means first answer for the question 1, `1_2` means, the second answer for the question 1

My goal was to run a Multiple Linear Regression to understand the relationship between image rating to answers that they provided for questions. My concern here is that each image can have multiple quality rating from multiple users plus each one of them could answer differently. Unlike classic where each row is a unique scenario.

In order to run the analysis is `R` I was going to combine `user_id`, and `image_id` to obtain unique identifier

Are there any red flags in following:

```
Image Quality ~ 1_1 + 1_2 + 1_3 + 1_4 + ... + 3_5
```

Is there a better analysis? Instead of Multiple Regression?

Comment: From your description, it sounds like subjects could indicate both that an image made them sad and that they had no feelings about the image. Is this correct?

Comment: @Kodiologist I made mistake edited the question.

Comment: Thanks. I also notice that you say you asked three questions (per image, presumably), but your dataset has columns going up to 5_5, which presumably means the fifth answer choice for the fifth question. So how many questions are there actually?

Comment: @Kodiologist three questions - Thanks. I edited but should that be an issue, having too many questions?

Comment: Are you interested in predicting user ratings from their emotional responses or emotional responses from their ratings? Also, you should definitely be using a multilevel model with subject ID as a random effect. If you use the same three images for each participant, you need a fixed effect for image ID. If there are many images, you can use another random effect for image ID in a cross-classified model.

Comment: @Noah Initially I wanted to predict user ratings from their emotional responses but now that you pointed out other way around i am interested in both. I don't understand what you saying about subject ID as a random effect and image ID in a cross classified model..... any chance giving an example?